# How can I partition dagster assets by year?

Tags: dagster

Not seeing a built in definition to partition assets by year (just hourly-monthly). Is there a way to manipulate the built in time definitions to accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TimeWindowPartitionsDefinition` to create your custom time partition

```py
from dagster import TimeWindowPartitionsDefinition

year_window_partition = TimeWindowPartitionsDefinition(
    start=dt.datetime(2023, 4, 1),
    cron_schedule="1 1 1 1 *",
    fmt="%Y"
)
```